# Balcony forest clearing

Tags: indoors, drainage

<sub>Please edit away the title to anything more suitable; I am not a native English speaker.</sub>

Now to the point. An apartment in temperate climate. A garden of about half a cubic meter of soil spread in pots. My dream is to transfer this into about 2 cubic meters of "one-big-pot" resulting in a home-owned forest clearing with grass one can sit on and some tomatoes/beans/lattices/etc to marvel at.

My first idea was a rubber pool liner inside a ytong-constructed cube. After some experiments with carefully watering plants in a no-drainage pots I concluded that as absurd.

The next modification is a 20cm layer of coarse stones, wrapped in stainless mesh on the bottom of it and a small pipe to allow drainage.

How does that sound?

Comment: Could you please add a photo of the cube you plan on using as a planter?

Comment: And looking at the plans from another angle: Have you checked the statics? Two cubic meters of wet soil plus drainage, framing, plants... is *a lot of weight*!

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate, in any case similar enough to be worth checking out: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30000/can-i-build-a-soil-based-garden-on-a-concrete-balcony

Comment: @Stephie indeed very relevant! But both answers say "no". But I am going to build this thing this winter and update my question with photos and with stories of all the ways it can go wrong.